# Why does this assignment break my program?

Tags: c

I am learning C and I'm not sure how to phrase this, but why does uncommenting line 11 in the following code break this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("argc: %d\n", argc);

    char *states[] = {};
    int i = 0;
    while(i < argc) {
        printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        //states[i] = "test";  
        i++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

When I uncomment this line and run the program I get this:

```
greggery@Lubu:~/code$ ./myprog aaa bbb ccc
argc: 4
arg 0: ./lc
arg 1: aaa
```

Why is `states[i] = "test";` breaking the `while` loop? When I comment it out I see all the arguments printed.

Comment: Well, for one, `states` is of size zero. You should give it a size. Maybe `char *states[argc];`, if you’re allowed VLAs.

Comment: C doesn't allow for arrays of length 0 nor for initializers to be empty. Maybe these are extensions that your compiler allows (not a good idea) but most probably you haven't had the warning level high enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It breaks because the array `states` is empty. Make it the size of `argc` (that's allowed in C99) to fix the problem:

```
char *states[argc];
```

The reason for this is as follows: `char *states[] = {};` makes an array of zero elements, so any dereference `states[i]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to do. I forgot you can't do that in C. But I'm still confused about the undefined behavior. Is the program just bombing out when it gets to line 11 so i is never incremented?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is just that -- it can, according to the C specification, have *any* effect on your program, because the specification doesn't say what happens. In your case, it is possible that the `i` variable is getting overwritten with some random pointer value, causing the loop to stop prematurely.

Comment: @user1028270: You’re probably changing `i`. I can reproduce it on 64-bit Linux/gcc by declaring `i` before `char* states[] = {};` and making it a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the character array. If argc is the number of characters you want to store:

```
char *states[argc];
```

Works. Or if you want to dynamically expand it you can use the heap, keep a counter variable and add the following in your loop:

```
states = (char *) realloc(sizeStates + sizeof(char));
sizeStates++;
```

To make room for the next character before you assign it.

Comment: Should be `sizeof(char*)`, not `sizeOf(char)`.